# Prompt for boot order

Tags: windows, usb, installation, windows-10-preview

I have an HDD lying around, and I would like to install Windows 10 Technical Preview on it and run it off USB. Is there a way for my HP Envy laptop to prompt at boot if I would like to boot from USB or from the internal SSD?

I know I can change the boot order in the BIOS, but is there a way to choose each time I start the computer?

Comment: [I use easy Bcd to do this](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1), you don't have to register to download and use, just click "download" button, its free. You should first assign a drive letter to the usb drive in disk management, assign a letter further down the alphabet so that no other usb device will be assigned that letter. No need to use the bios. [tutorials here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/bcd-based/windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have UEFI, there is an application, EasyUEFI, http://www.easyuefi.com/index.html, which can change the boot device order on the next reboot from within Windows. As with any executable, especially one operating at such a low level, check for malware before using with a thorough tool such as VirusTotal, https://www.virustotal.com/.